# Use factory method to construct base object for inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, factory

I have a class, something like this:

```
public class User {
  public User() {
    // this constructor creates an object representing a brand new user
  }

  public static User Get(MyDbObject dbObject) {
    // this factory method creates an object representing an existing user, from a database object
  }
}
```

and an inherited class, like this:

```
public class ExtendedUser : User {
  public object ExtendedProperty { get; set; }

  public static ExtendedUser Get(MyDbObject dbObj) {
    User usr = User.Get(dbObj);
    this = usr; // this does NOT work
    this.ExtendedProperty = "just an example";
  }
}
```

Originally this was all working using overloaded constructors which created an object from the MyDbObject record, so ExtendedUser had a constructor like this:

```
public ExtendedUser(MyDbObject dbObj) : base(dbObj) {
  this.ExtendedProperty = "another example, this is how it WAS working";
}
```

I want to get away from using constructors to create these objects in favor of factory methods, but I'm not groking how to assign the base instance/object without calling the constructor. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to use factory methods instead of constructors?

Answer (score 2):

Factory methods know how to create specific instances of a class, not usually the base class. Instead you can have a protected constructor on the base class for this purpose:

```
    public class User {
      public User() {
        // this constructor creates an object representing a brand new user
      }

      protected User(MyDbObject dbObject) {
        // creates an object representing an existing user, from a database object
      }

      public static User GetUser(MyDbObject dbObject) {
        return User(dbObject);
      }
    }

    public class ExtendedUser : User {
      public object ExtendedProperty { get; set; }

      private ExtendedUser(MyDbObject dbObject) : base(dbObject)
      {
        //add extra data onto the base class here
      }

      public static ExtendedUser GetExtendedUser(MyDbObject dbObj) {
        return new ExtendedUser(dbObject);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Accidentally made the base class and inherited class have the same static method... I fixed it in an edit.